Why this formula cannot be used here?
My book says

Why can't I apply it to
$$g(x)=\int_{0}^{x}e^{x-t}dt$$
Which gives $g'(x)=e^{x-x}$
but when we integrate properly we get $g'(x)=e^x$
What I thought
$g(x)=\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}f(t,x)dt$
As we are integrating in the t world (though we later substitute it's bounds in terms of u,v) that x has nothing to do as changes in x,t are independent so we could just say let
$\frac{dF(t,x)}{dt}=f(t,x)\cdots (1)$
$g(x)=F(v(x),x)-F(u(x),x)$
$g'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}F(v(x),x)-\frac{d}{dx}F(u(x),x)$
Now in (1) we can put $t=u(x),v(x)$ one by one to get $dt=u'dx,v'dx $respectively
To get
$$g'(x)=v'f(v,x)-u'f(u,x)$$
If I'm wrong Please help me find my mistake also try to reply according to the level of a high school student and feel free to add some more advices and things which are relevant here if required
Thanks in advance!

Because your $f$ depends on $x$. In your case you can simply factor out $e^x$ from the integrand and use the porduct rule. In general, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

The formula assumes that the integrand $f(t)$ is only a function of $t$. But $e^{x-t}$ is $x$-dependent, so the formula doesn't apply as written. By contrast, the version on Wikipedia here does assume an integrand $f(x,t)$ and thus includes an extra term to account for this. (In the present case, you could also write this as $g(x)=e^x\int_0^x f(t)~dt$. Differentiating according to the product rule then allows your version of Liebniz to be applied.)

In the formula, the function to be integrate only depends on $t$, while yours depends on both $t$ and $x$. In this case you can easily move forward just by noting that $e^{x-t} = e^x e^{-t}$:
$$
g'(x)=\frac{d}{dx} \left(\int_0^x e^{x-t} dt \right) = \frac{d}{dx}\left( e^{x} \int_0^x e^{-t}dt\right)
$$
Now, computing the derivative of a product, you get
$$
g'(x) = e^{x}\int_0^{x}e^{-t} dt + e^x e^{-x} = e^x(-e^{-x}+e^0)+1=2+e^x
$$
where you used the formula from your book to compute the derivate of the integral.
